# "vue - electron" how to custom top menu bar?

Tags: vue.js, electron

vue is developing desktop applications using electron,
I'd like to customize the menu bar on the top. I'd like to move all the menu elements to Title bar? How do I do it?

before
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zhNw.png)

i want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAMi0.png)

Comment: Natively, this is not possible. You would need to build your own custom title bar / menu  from HTML / CSS / JS for this to work.

Comment: A quick Google search revealed [this NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-electron-titlebar) which *might* be of help. Seems as though you wouldn't need to modify your renderer script, but I have no experience with it.